# Android emulator constantly rebooting on Ubuntu Maverick

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-emulator, restart, reboot

and thank you for your time.

I am using Titanium Appcelerator to write an app for Android, and as compared to Windows, where the emulator was quite stable, in Linux I get the following symptoms:

- emulator restart with no reason, sometimes after a runtime error, sometimes right after launching my app, and sometimes just right after booting completely after being launched
- emulator informs that "process $1 is not responding", where $1 is generally the system process, but sometimes may be acore, or the calendar. This may happen while installing my app on the emulator, right after loading it, or right after unlocking the screen.

As it is easy to imagine, testing code like this can be quite difficult, so I was wondering, has anyone else stumbled upon this problem, and/or know how it could be solved?

Thank you very much in advance, and pls let me know of any info I should provide.

Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify that the emulator is working fine without Appcelerator first. Definitely update to the latest SDK (r8) and create a new emulator AVD and see if the problem is there without Appcelerator.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for replying! In fact, an emulator made by the SDK Manager will work just fine, whereas my Titanium-made emulator works erratically even if launched from outside of Titanium.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution, but I don't claim it is universally valid: I just erased the virtual device created under Titanium, changed the project file for it to use SDK 1.4.2, and had it launched again under 1.4.2. It certainly didn't build my app, but at least it created a new virtual device, which I use now to build against 1.5.0, working like a charm so far.

Thanks again Manfred for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I guess you should accept my answer then ;-) Anyway I dont know about Titanium but what sdk versions are you talking about? If you are talking about Java SDK I would suggest to use one of the latest 1.6 release that comes with your distro. Use the Oracle/Sun JDK. That has no issues whatsoever for me in Ubuntu.

Comment: Indeed, I'm sorry I had no idea what those arrows around the big number were for :) The SDK versions I mentioned are for the Titanium Mobile SDK. As for the Android SDK, I'm using apis-1.6. I'll be more precise next time, thanks very much!